# loading array data init immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm loading array data into my reducer this is how I'm currently going about it, it's working, is there a better way more verbose to achieve this ? 
i've been through the docs but they appear to be written is some weird form of hieroglyphics

```
action.data = [{key: "value"},{key: "value2"}]
// ...

const initialState = Immutable.Map({
  loading: false,
  data: Immutable.List([]),
})

    case RECEIVE_DATA:
      return state 
        .set('data', Immutable.List(action.data.map(item => Immutable.Map(item))))
```

Comment: use fromJS to deeply convert js data to immutable data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the [fromJS()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS) function to be easier:

> fromJS() deeply converts plain JS objects and arrays to Immutable Maps
>   and Lists.

Example:

```
action.data = [{key: "value"},{key: "value2"}]
// ...

const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  loading: false,
  data: [],
})

// ...
    case RECEIVE_DATA:
      return state.set('data', Immutable.fromJS(action.data))
```

Comment: i think this is what I'm looking for, although i think `const initialState = Immutable.Map({` as loading is a state value

Comment: Using `const initialState = Immutable.Map({...})` won't convert your `data` array into a List. You'd have to do that manually inside the object you pass to `Map()`. It'll definitely be simpler to just use `fromJS()`. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "loading is a state value"?

Comment: sorry i didn't see this comment before i edited it. https://jsbin.com/cohenojape/edit?js,console,output is basically what i was trying to get to. the value loading doesn't come from js any where so i think its more appropriate to keep it as a property of the state i.e. inside a map of the state.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `Immutable.List.of`?

```
action.data = [{key: "value"},{key: "value2"}]
// ...

const initialState = Immutable.Map({
  loading: false,
  data: Immutable.List([]),
})

    case RECEIVE_DATA:
      return state 
        .set('data', Immutable.List.of(action.data))
```

Comment: you'd have to do it with spread operators `.set('data', Immutable.List.of(...action.data))` but it's better i guess

Comment: Or you could just call `Immutable.List(action.data)`. I personally prefer this because it signifies intended data structure, whereas `fromJS` could be anything

Comment: `List()` won't convert the inner objects from `action.data` into Maps, it would just result in a List of native JS objects. Mixing Immutable with native types will get confusing, it's preferable to have the entire structure be Immutable. `fromJS()` just changes arrays to Lists and objects to Maps, it's very simple and predictable.

Comment: good point. i wasn't sure about this either at first, (if you put data into an immutable List that isn't immutable is it immutable ?). I figured it was best to keep nesting immutable structures and use either maps or records, then you can .get() each property.